# Job 1:4-5: Why does Job not discipline his sinning sons instead of bailing them out all the time?

Tags: sin, sacrifice, atonement, repentance

> 4 And his sons visiting one another prepared a banquet every day,
> taking with them also their three sisters to eat and drink with them.
> 5 And when the days of the banquet were completed, Job sent and
> purified them, having risen up in the morning, and offered sacrifices
> for them, according to their number, and one calf for a sin-offering
> for their souls: for Job said, Lest peradventure my sons have thought
> evil in their minds against God. Thus, then Job did all the days.

Though many take the parties Job's children held rather lightly, there are some considerations that suggest dire implications looming large for Job and his household.

1. The sons are getting drunk every day, at least Job seems to think so.
2. Drunkenness in the OT is associated with unwise and shameful behaviour and uncovering yourself.
3. The daughters are taken to these drinking bouts!
4. The sons seem to show no signs of repentance.
5. At the rate Job is making atonement by sin-offering 7 calves a day, even his wealth is in serious jeopardy.

Why doesn't Job just discipline his sons and end this vicious cycle of sin, sacrifice and atonement, isn't it his duty as father to teach his children the commandments instead?

Comment: What translation are you using ? _And his sons have gone and made a banquet -- the house of each `in' his day -- and have sent and called to their three sisters to eat and to drink with them;_ (YLT) gives no grounds for what is being inferred above. What is wrong with having a banquet ? ? ? _Perhaps my sons have sinned, yet blessed God in their heart.'_ (YLT).

Answer (score 14):

When the Bible says that his sons feasted, it is not "every day" - it is on "every one ***his*** day". That might have been his birthday. Or, it could have been that the sons all took turns to hold a feast, going on a rota. But there is no indication that these feasts were every day of the week!

If they had been, then the sacrifices Job offered would, indeed, have amounted to a huge slaughter.  That, however, is an unwarranted assumption. It could have been ***no more than seven annual feasts***, each one marking a son's particular birthday.

There is nothing in the book of Job that says his sons sinned during those celebrations with their sisters. It only shows that Job - their father - was not present. Therefore, **in case they had sinned,** he made those offerings to God. Note that the only thing he states as worrying him is "in case they have sinned and cursed God in their hearts" (vs. 5). This is how the K.J.V. words it. Also, it adds that Job carried out the purification rituals ***"continually",*** not every day. It would be helpful to state which Bible translation you have quoted.

Further, the sons were showing due diligence in looking after their sisters by including them. The sisters would be under their protection on those feast days. Nothing is said about the siblings getting drunk. Nothing is said about repentance, for if they had not sinned, they would not need to repent. Job was just being conscientious, performing a purification ritual **in case** they had sinned.

Finally, "the commandments" had not been issued that early in the Bible. Job is reckoned to be the oldest book in the Bible, written before Moses started writing the first five. It is not placed first because nobody knows the dates involved, but there are many indications that it was more ancient that the writing of Genesis. The book of Job should not be read as if it followed the issuing of the Law. By doing that, far more is being read into the account than is warranted.

Comment: Up-voted +1. This restores balance to the discussion and correctly reports the text of Job rather than the wild suppositions of those who seem to want to condemn Job without proper evidence.

Comment: +1. Good balanced answer

Answer (score 2):

How do we know that he did not teach them? Or at least tried to teach them. We can learn from Proverbs ch5 or from our own observation that some sons simply don't listen to their parents. Surely we have to assume that they are grown-up and unwilling to accept paternal discipline. Just as the people of the two kingdoms would not submit to God's discipline and he was obliged to judge them and bring the kingdoms to an end.

Anyway, the atonement was not succesful in the long term, when God lost patience; "If your children have sinned against him, he has delivered them into the power of their transgressions" (ch8 v4).

Answer (score 1):

Although, Job 1 does not say that any of the sons were sinning, I certainly agree that Job 1 is using connections to Genesis 9 -- the first mention of drinking alcohol in the Bible -- to put the idea in our head that something dire is about to happen.

> (Genesis 9:19-27) These were the three sons of Noah, and from them
> came the people who were scattered over the whole earth.
>
> Noah, a man of the soil, proceeded to plant a vineyard. When he drank
> some of its wine, he became drunk and lay uncovered inside his tent.
> Ham, the father of Canaan, saw his father naked and told his two
> brothers outside.
>
> But Shem and Japheth took a garment and laid it across their
> shoulders; then they walked in backward and covered their father’s
> naked body. Their faces were turned the other way so that they would
> not see their father naked.
>
> When Noah awoke from his wine and found out what his youngest son had
> done to him, he said, “Cursed be Canaan! The lowest of slaves will he
> be to his brothers.”

Both accounts feature a famously righteous father with a number of children. There are 3 sons in the of Noah, and in Job's case there are 7 sons and 3 daughters.

In Genesis 9 we have the father getting drunk and then being covered by his two sons, while in Job 1 we have the father "covering" the children who have been drinking.

In Genesis Noah curses his eldest son, whereas Job is concerned that the sons have cursed God in their hearts.

Only a few verses before this event, Noah was the first to build an altar to offer burnt animals:

> (Genesis 8: 20-21) Then Noah built an altar to the Lord and, taking
> some of all the clean animals and clean birds, he sacrificed burnt
> offerings on it.
>
> The Lord smelled the pleasing aroma and said in his heart: “Never
> again will I curse the ground because of humans, even though every
> inclination of the human heart is evil from childhood."

So, Job 1 is comparing itself to Genesis 9 to increase the tension, remind the audience that in the Bible all men -- even the righteous fall horribly.

However, and although we are primed to expect the fall of Job, he has been established as the protagonist, and we are on his side -- desperately WANT to see him delivered and vindicated.

Next in the story, it begins to innovate on themes from the Garden of Eden:

- Nakedness without sin (Genesis 2:25, Job 1:21-22
- Being protected and blessed (Genesis 2:8-10, Job 1:9) Creatures present themselves (Genesis 2:19, Job 1:6, 2:1)
- A reference to flesh and bones (Genesis 2:23, Job 2:5)
- An accuser who wants to make man experience hardship (Genesis 3:1, Job 1:10, 2:5)
- A wife who tempts her husband to invoke cursing and death (Genesis 3:6, Job 2:9)

The next section of Job is a cycle of speeches. This main section of the book, is comparable to the animals being presented to Adam in order to find a "defender before him" (Genesis 2: 19-20). None of those presented to him fulfilled the requirements. Adam was then lowered, then when he was raised up a woman was brought to him and in the climax of the chapter 2, he asserts her equality to him:

> (Genesis 2: 23) The man said, “This is now bone of my bones and flesh
> of my flesh".

So in the speeches in Job, none of his friends are able to stand up for him, yet he maintains that "I know that my redeemer lives, and that in the end he will stand on the earth. And after my skin has been destroyed, yet in my flesh I will see God; I myself will see him with my own eyes -— I, and not another. How my heart yearns within me!" (Job 19:25-27)

Here we see that although Job is righteous, just like Adam was without sin, there was a problem ... he is in need of a face-to-face relationship with God himself. It wasn't the possible sins of his sons that created Job's insecurities, it was his own need of God.

However the story doesn't end there. Just like revelation taught from God to Adam prompted him to assert the equality of Eve, so Job's revelation of his standing before God prompted him to see something he had never noticed before. His original three daughters had been treated as lesser than their brothers.

But now, after having a revelation of the power and wisdom of God, Job sees things differently.  In the climax of the resolution of the book, Job has three daughters ... and he treats equal to his sons.

Job (42:15) Nowhere in all the land were there found women as beautiful as Job’s daughters, and their father granted them an inheritance along with their brothers.

So Job's problem was not disciplining his son's but instead honouring his daughters as bearers of God's image.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the new situation after the restoration of Job's fortune, especially the improved status of the daughters, they even got names now. But there seems to be even more improvement. Before his ordeal Job was very rich, but he also seemed very alone with all his worries about the sons sins, now he is in harmony with his social environment and he himself can host a banquet in generous reciprocity to gifts from his family and acquaintances who earlier despised him when he was down. That maybe showed some opportunism, but above all a restoration of harmony.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot stop a desirability and charm of wickedness by an outward censure. Of course Job's sons and daughters knew that living in such a futile way was a pain for their father, but they still practiced it. With outward censure they would have stopped doing it, while in their hearts still desiring it, but in addition they would have started hating their father Job, starting to think about him as about a stern policeman, a killjoy, a harsh bigot. Thus, sometimes it is better to let or be indulgent to sin (in others of course!) than to try to stop it by an outward compulsion, which will not heal it, but make it more latent and venomous.

My friend, a faithful and saintly deacon said to me once: "I have given to my 18-years old brother 500 $ that he may go with his friends to a beach town with girls, alcohol and fun there, that he may wholeheartedly and freely have a good and cool time with his friends!" My friend himself has only one fun in his life: to pray to Lord, study theological literature, + also to listen to classical music, but for his brother he wanted that the latter could be as free and happy as containable in his heart and taste, not to check him in a bigoted fashion, not reprimand him, not trying to impose his own life-style and values on him, but give in to him and try to see the world with his eyes.

It is not a stinking postmodern relativity (abominable even to mention!), but a Christian wisdom and empathy, which eventually will lead a person -  treated in this manner by an advanced Christian - to innerly change and embrace sanctity not as something imposed from outside, but as something that is intrinsically attractive and desirable. That's why a bishop of Carthago did not forbid young Augustine to read heretical literature, that he might come to truth on his own understanding and his own soul-searching.

And thus, the charm and desirability of sinfulness and wickedness is overcome not by any outward compulsion, but by the inner repentive motivation towards the beyond-comparison-ly greater a charm, greater a coolness, greater a mystery and desirability of sanctity, and enticement of divine terrible goodness.